# How to parse this complex array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this structure coming from an array dump:

```
0 => 
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'start' => string '12:30:00' (length=8)
  public 'end' => string '12:45:00' (length=8)
  public 'structure' => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'structure_id' => int 5
      public 'structure_name' => string 'LABORATORY 1' (length=18)
  public 'specialist' => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'specialist_id' => int 222
      public 'specialist_surname' => string 'Smith' (length=7)
      public 'specialist_name' => string 'John' (length=9)
      public 'specialist_signature' => string 'Dr.' (length=3)
  public 'price' => float 80.5
1 => 
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'start' => string '12:30:00' (length=8)
  public 'end' => string '12:45:00' (length=8)
  public 'structure' => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'structure_id' => int 5
      public 'structure_name' => string 'LABORATORY 4' (length=18)
  public 'specialist' => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'specialist_id' => int 222
      public 'specialist_surname' => string 'White' (length=7)
      public 'specialist_name' => string 'Jack' (length=9)
      public 'specialist_signature' => string 'Dr.' (length=3)
  public 'price' => float 80.5
2 => 
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'start' => string '12:30:00' (length=8)
  public 'end' => string '12:45:00' (length=8)
  public 'structure' => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'structure_id' => int 5
      public 'structure_name' => string 'LABORATORY 9' (length=18)
  public 'specialist' => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'specialist_id' => int 222
      public 'specialist_surname' => string 'Brown' (length=7)
      public 'specialist_name' => string 'Lester' (length=9)
      public 'specialist_signature' => string 'Dr.' (length=3)
  public 'price' => float 80.5
```

How to parse it with PHP? In particular, I would like to assign values to normal PHP variables in order to print them or to put into an HTML table.

Comment: Can you just do print_r?

Comment: Why go through all the overhead of assigning values from this array of objects to variables; just access them as they are when you need them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can access this structure like this

```
echo $object[0]->start;
echo $object[0]->end;
echo $object[0]->structure->specialist_id;
```

> This will result

```
12:30:00
12:45:00
5
```

Why do you need variables for this? That will result in too many vars. Instead use a loop to iterate over the object and access the inner objects using "->"

Comment: Great,Jabran!!! :-)

I define $object by passing to this variable the object coming from the array (which is actually a JSONed array). So I've solved this way:

$object = json_decode($response->result);

$response->result comes from a CURL call, which queries a web service and get 'result' in return.

Again, thank you!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of the [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) on PHP

```
<?php
$size = "large";
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");
echo "$color, $size, $shape, $wddx_size\n";
?>
```

> OUTPUT :blue, large, sphere, medium